# Xamarin iOS - Share UINavigationController in all app

Tags: ios, xamarin, controller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I want to share my NavigationBar to all my viewControllers.
So, I create a parent controller that I implemented to all my viewControllers.

But when I make a `Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ControllerCustom");`
I got a navigationBar with the default "Back" button..

What can I do ?

Thanks for answers

Comment: Please provide some related code, then we can help you locate the problem.

Comment: BTW, I test on my side. It works fine for me.